# Getting all font families in React JS

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, font-family, google-fonts

I am new to ReactJS. I am trying to display all the font families in a dropdown, so that if i select one of the font family the text (displayed in a SVG) font-family will change. 
I know in .net we can use System.Drawing.FontFamily.Families to get all the font familes. Like wise in react is there anything? Or else is there any other way to do this? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all the available fonts on current machine, right?
I think there is no way to do that.

But with some trick we still can list almost available fonts on the current machine with:

**1. A list of fonts**

- [Windows fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows)
- [Mac fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_macOS)
- [Some common fonts](http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html)

**2. JavaScript font detector**

http://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html

You got the idea, right? Now we just need to check what fonts are available in our font list and display them in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a web application using React, then it is impossible. For that matter, it is impossible with any library or framework. There is no JS API exposed by browsers that allow you get a list of all the fonts installed in the system (It can be a security issue).

However, if you are using React to build a Desktop application using electron.js or node-webkit.js, then you can export a binding for system API call to JavaScript and get this list. But it is a very cumbersome process. (I thought of this because you are comparing **.net API** with **Web API**.)

In general, as @Jared suggested, that is what most of the online(web applications) tools do when they want to provide font-selection dropdown for users.